# PHP Slim framework "two named subpatterns have the same name"

Tags: php, slim

When I try to add a new route to my router, I got this weird error:
`preg_match(): Compilation failed: two named subpatterns have the same name at offset 39`

I've already checked my router for double routes, changed the route name but it doesn't work.

This is my route:
`Route::resource('/visitor/:id', 'Visitors\Controllers\EditVisitorController')`

Does anybody know that this problem could be?

Comment: If that's all you're going to post, I'm not sure how you expect us to help

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32452479/how-to-have-a-detailed-trace-of-a-slim-application-error?noredirect=1#comment52775836_32452479). What I did was get a detailed trace of the error. The detailed trace will give you the routes that have conflicts. An example of my code to debug my error is this:

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
    'debug' => false
));
$app->error(function (\Exception $e) use ($app) {
    //enter manipulation of $e->getTrace()
    //or just var_dump($e->getTrace()) but the format would be chaotic
});
```